# Node.js: Can't get tls.connect to work, error: "unable to verify the first certificate"

Tags: node.js, ssl, starttls

Building a node.js application that uses

```
tls.connect({
    host: 'imap.domain.com',
    port: 993,
    tls: true,
})
```

to connect to an imap server. I cannot get it to work. When trying to connect to the server, I just get an error: "unable to verify the first certificate" and whatever I do, I can't get past it.

Added *ssl-root-cas* to the *tls.connect(options) options.ca* but it still dosn't work.

Comment: Though it's not a good solution, you can try to pass `rejectUnauthorized : false` along with other params to get it work.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! So, something might be wrong with my environment. I ran the exact same code on Windows instead of Mac and it worked without errors. Any suggestions on what might be wrong?

Comment: Probably, certificate is not present in your trusted store. Probably you can try to add it in `keychain` in your macbook.

Comment: How exactly do you do this?

Comment: It's not a a server error, I've been trying to connect to imap.gmail.com, works on Windows not on Mac

Comment: Found out what it was. Had Avast installed and it destroyed m keychain adding their own CA.